# Quickly select .Net 4.x in an old project?

Tags: vb.net

I was mystified why I didn't have MemoryStream.CopyTo, until I noticed my project is set to use .Net 2.x!

Is there a simple way to update all my references to 4.x? There's a lot of them.

Comment: Change it in the project that has the code you are trying to use.  And the EXE project.  The rest don't actually matter.  Doing them all quickly can be done with Edit + Find and Replace + Replace in Files to modify the `<TargetFramework>` value in *.vbproj.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the target framework, not individual references.  In the project properties, look for the "Compile" section.  Under "Advanced Compile Options" there is the option to change the framework to .NET 4+.